# Having issues converting VBA.NET function to PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

There's a following function written in VBA.NET which I'm trying convert to PHP. I'm primarly a PHP developer, and I have alsmost zero-knowledge in VB.

```
<%

Public Shared Function ComputeHash(ByVal Key As String) As String
    Dim objSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
        objSHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key.ToCharArray))
    Dim buffer() As Byte = objSHA1.Hash
    Dim HashValue As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
    Return HashValue
End Function

%>
```

I have tried searching for manuals and found some guidelances. 
This is so far what I have converted to PHP myself:

```
function compute_hash($string){
    return base64_encode(sha1($string));
}
```

Hovewer it doesn't produce the same result as VB's function `ComputeHash()`. Coudn't someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Example of execution on both languages:

VBA.NET

```
string = "orange45877687459999SENTRYORD01154321"

ComputeHash(string) // Returns = WbwSWEBzPqgo9C4nZmGwHhd/FBQ=
```

PHP

```
$string = "orange45877687459999SENTRYORD01154321";

compute_hash(string) // Returns = NTliYzEyNTg0MDczM2VhODI4ZjQyZTI3NjY2MWIwMWUxNzdmMTQxNA== (but I need "WbwSWEBzPqgo9C4nZmGwHhd/FBQ=")
```

Comment: What is your target to achieve ?? Do you want to return a hash by sha1 in ??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI No, it's not that simple actually. Not just hash itself. I'm looking for exact equalient of `ComputeHash()` in PHP

Comment: Can you post some sample inputs and outputs you receive?

Comment: Do not forget the utf8 encoding in your function ? 
    return base64_encode(utf8_encode(sha1($string)));

Comment: @HankyPanky Added examples of output hashes in both languages

Comment: @Snoozer `utf8_encode()` makes no any difference

Comment: I have find a post similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336017/same-string-different-sha1-hash-values-obtained-from-vb-net-and-php

In my opinion the problem comes from base64 encoding
Trying to compare without base64 encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instruct PHP to return the SHA1-hash in bytes instead of in hex format, by passing the TRUE parameter to the hashing function:

```
function compute_hash($string){
    return base64_encode(sha1($string, TRUE));
}
```

[PHP manual for SHA1](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)